# Convergece of Steepest Descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

Why does Steepest Descent converge? I know that will be take the objective $f$ and walk it through direction $-\nabla f$ with step size $\alpha_k$ but step size seems able to be negative and it does the function walk to maximum direction intead minimum.

Look at:

$x_{k+1}=x_{k}+\alpha_{k}d_k$

Where:

$\alpha_k=argmin_{\alpha}f(x_{k}+\alpha.d_k)$

$d_k=-\nabla f(x_k)$

There is no any reason in the math to $\alpha_k$ always be greater than 0.

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha_k$ being greater than zero is a *precondition*; for example, see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) that uses $\gamma$ as your $\alpha_k$.

> for a $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}_+$ small enough, then $F(\mathbf{a_n}) \geq F(\mathbf{a_{n+1}})$...

If $\alpha_k$ were negative, you'd recover steepest *ascent*. (Traditionally, you'd treat this as a positive $\alpha_k$ and use $+\nabla f(x_k)$ for $d_k$.)

Comment: Set $d_k=\nabla f(x_k)$ if $\alpha_k>0$ it would solve the problem but that approach doesn't belong to algorithm. I would like to proof the convergence of Steepest Descent as i've mentioned where $\alpha_k=argmin_{\alpha}f(x_k+\alpha.d_k)$ and $d_k$ is always negative gradient of $f$.

Comment: No, it wouldn’t solve the problem. I think you’ve copied down the algorithm wrong; where is $\alpha$‘s domain defined?

Comment: $\alpha_k$ is real valuated, I've copied this one from (Robert M. Freund 2004) and (Juan C. Meza 2010)